# Angular 5 ng-Dragula after table sort not dragging correct row

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, ngdraggable

I am having two table in my Angular application . In first table i filter record using Angular pipe and then i drag these filter rows to second table . But after filter ng- dragula not able drag correct row i.e after drag destination table show some other row data. can anyone please help me to understand what wrong i am doing.

Source table is :

```
        <tr *ngFor="let FineTunedData of FineTunedDatas | orderBy: key : reverse | familieFilter: family | searchfilter:filter | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: f, id: 'f' };
          let i = index" (click)="setClickedRow(i)"  [class.active]="i == selectedRow" (click)="GetCustomerDetails(FineTunedData)" 
          >            
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.article_ID}}</td>
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.description}}</td>          
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.stockRAW}}</td>          
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.ordersRAW}}</td>
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.family}}</td>              
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.toProduceForecast}}</td>  
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.toProduce}}</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="placeholder" *ngIf="!table1?.length > 0" id="no-drop">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>  
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

and destination table is:

`<tbody  [dragula]='"bag"' [dragulaModel]='FineTunedDatas'> 
          <tr *ngFor="let FineTunedData of FineTunedDatas let i = index"
           [class.active]="i == selectedRow" [attr.data-id]="i" (click)="getLSomeValue(i, FineTunedData)">

            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.article_ID}}</td>
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.description}}</td>
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.navisionCode}}</td>

            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.stockRAW}}</td>

            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.ordersRAW}}</td>
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.family}}</td>
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.toProduceForecast}}</td>

            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.toProduce}}</td>

          </tr>
          <tr class="placeholder" dragHandle=".ui-panel-titlebar">

              <td class="th"></td>
              <td class="th"></td>
              <td class="th"></td>
              <td class="th"></td>
              <td class="th"></td>
              <td class="th"></td>
              <td class="th"></td>
              <td class="th"></td>

          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>`

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Tables require the bag and model from Dragula to be assigned to the `tbody`. Can you please post your component code?

Comment: I have updated my question with code

Comment: The source table tbody element is same as destination table tbody element. I copied that code also but don't know why it is not showing here